# powerbi, sum of distinct value and filter for another column

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have the following table and am trying to get the sum of a particular column. [First Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVxA8.png)

I would like to take distinct values for the 'TrackerID' and when durationConnected is greater than 0, then take the value greater than 0. In the end I would like to get the sum which in this case is 7. (See second table):

[Second Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEHNc.png)

I tried creating another table by doing the following: AnotherTableTest = SUMMARIZE(journal;journal[PhoneNumber];journal[StartTime];journal[TrackerID];"UniqueCalls";DISTINCTCOUNT(journal[TrackerID]);"TimeConnected";Max(journal[DurationConnected])). This didn't give me the expected result.

I also tried using a measure: 
MaxAmount = MAX(journal[DurationConnected])
ActualAmount = SUMX(DISTINCT(journal[TrackerID]);[MaxAmount])

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new table like this:

```
newTable = SUMMARIZECOLUMNS('journal'[TrackerID],
    "StartTime", MAX('journal'[StartTime]),
    "totalDuration",SUM('journal'[DurationConnected]))
```

**EDIT** 
When `[DurationConnected]` is the only value that changes for each `[TrackerID]`, this answer is a bit cleaner. I also added `'journal'[Outbound]` on OP's request (see comments).

```
newTable = SUMMARIZECOLUMNS('journal'[TrackerID],
    ('journal'[StartTime]),('journal'[Outbound]),
    "totalDuration",SUM('journal'[DurationConnected]))
```

Comment: If I run the following: newTable = SUMMARIZECOLUMNS('journal'[TrackerID],'journal'[StartTime],'journal'[PhoneNumber],"totalDuration",SUM('journal'[DurationConnected])) . I get a similar result to the Table 1 picture above (cannot add a screenshot here)

Comment: I don't understand your comment. In my answer i use the table shown in the [First Table] image as the startingpoint 'journal'

Comment: Hi Marco, thanks for your answer. I would like to have a chart where I have the journal[StartTime] on the xaxis and the total duration on the yaxis. In the case of the table above, I would have a total duration of 7 for 09.10.2018. If I take the max or the sum of total duration from the new table, it just results in a huge number for the total duration. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can just add the StartTime as a column of the new table. See my Edit.

Comment: Thanks Marco, that's great. I've one more question. I have another column called Outbound in the Journal table. This has values of 0 and 1, I'd like to add this column to the newtable. Could you let me know how I would do that? Thanks a lot.